# DATEDIFF - What is wrong with my SQL query?

Tags: sql

I have the table `ORDERS` and while trying to find the processing time for each order by subtracting the date of receipt from the date of delivery, I keep getting this error:

> SQL0206N  "DAY" is not valid in the context where it is used. 
>   SQLSTATE=42703

My query is the following:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, ReceiptDate, DeliveryDate) FROM ORDERS
```

I suspect it has something to do with the date's format in the columns `ReceiptDate` and `DeliveryDate`: DD/MM/YY. Does this have to be converted? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Is there an alternative for using DATEDIFF? Can I convert each individual date to an int of days and then subtract the two ints?

Comment: What is your database?  Is it SQL Server, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using DB2, then there is no `DATEDIFF` function, which is specific to SQL Server.  However, we can easily simulate it by taking a difference of days, using the `DAYS()` function:

```
SELECT DAYS(DeliveryDate) - DAYS(ReceiptDate) AS days_diff
FROM ORDERS;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The data type of the columns is already "date". This still gives me the same error.

Comment: If both columns are date/datetime, then the call to `DATEDIFF` should be working.  I don't have any other explanation.  Note that dates don't have a "format" internally.  You might be seeing the dates in this format from SSMS, but there is no actual format.

Comment: Indeed, I wasn't aware db2 doesn't use the DATEDIFF function. This works beautifully, thank you for your help.